# How to escape cyberstalking without losing points and reputation?

Tags: support, security, privacy

Suppose someone is cyberstalking me on Stack Exchange. They could gain quite a lot of insight on what I am doing by simply reading my posts.

I *could* create a new account, but that would mean losing all my points, badges, and reputation. Is it possible to change username and user ID for the purpose of escaping cyberstalking without losing points, badges, and reputation (and having all posts and bookmarks still accessible from the former account)?

Comment: What kind of insight they might get are you worried about, exactly?

Comment: If you're asking if you can have a fresh account with no posts associated to it, but still have your old reputation score and badge count... then No, that's not possible. But you can go back and expunge any personal information from your old posts just by editing them.

Comment: @JanDvorak I know more than a few people who avoid Stack Overflow because they are creating code for sensitive situations and don't want anyone to have unnecessary insight into what they're doing. Security through obscurity isn't a security solution, but adding it to the top of the pile of better security measures does put another difficulty in the path of anyone considering exploiting a system.

Comment: The problem is not with the posts that are already there. The problem is with new ones. If I post on Software Recommendations on a software that does X, or on Android Stack Exchange or Superuser a question regarding a particular app, than people will be able to figure out what I am up to, which can be a problem.

Comment: (a threat to my privacy, if I need to record wrongdoings by abusive parents with my smartphone using a voice recording, and I post something about sound files, for instance, they will be able to figure things out; if I post something about how to monitor logins on a device, they will know I am monitoring their access to my devices and stop doing it, so I will not be able to catch them in the act; if I post something about how to delete entries from a log file to see if they can do it to me, they will use this information to delete their misdoings; and so on...).

Comment: @JordanJamingsons So create the new account with irrelevant information, using a name from a random name generator, and ask the private question.  Better yet, log out, create an anonymous email address, and ask using that without registering for the site.  Why do you feel you need reputation for this process? It's free to ask and answer questions, simply post as a guest. If you want, register, but it's certainly unnecessary.

Comment: Another example of where one has to watch out. Suppose you are a memeber of a group that does not have many question. If you posted to such a group then there is a possibility that a cyberstalker with enough information could identify your post as being your own, and then find all your other Stack Exchange posts in this very way.

Comment: Let us not forget that a stalker could also be someone who used to live with you but no longer does yet temporarily shows up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even if possible, it would be quite pointless.

Finding you again based on your reputation and badges would be easy enough for one who really wants.

So, it's either starting a blank page, or accepting you have a stalker and being careful not to expose sensitive information about yourself that he/she might use against you. Since such information is considered noise in Stack Exchange (except in chat), it shouldn't be hard. :)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I hadn't thought about the possibility of reidentifying based on points and reputation. I was thinking that would be hard though even for a very competent professional stalker. Most would just assume you've disappeared from the site if they don't see any new posts belonging to you.

Comment: No problem, I once used this method to find someone who changed display name. Not 100% the same, but same method will work for someone who is really into finding you.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Well, you *are* the shadow wizard, after all.  No ordinary stalker.

Answer (score 7):

> Is it possible to change username and user ID for the purpose of escaping cyberstalking without losing points, badges, and reputation (and having all posts and bookmarks still accessible from the former account)?

No.  That would mean the old account has X reputation, and the new account would have X reputation - effectively doubling reputation, and giving it to a "new" user. Not only would this look strange ("Why does a 30k user have only a few posts and not enough upvotes for 30k?") but it would enable a number of possible abuses in the reputation system.

If a user is concerned about stalking, they may need to give up on the "reputation race" and have separate accounts for their various activities they don't want linked together or found out.

Comment: And, just to check, I've created a guest question on one of the sites, and it showed up on the question list.  All I had to enter was a name and email, and due to gmail's plus addressing scheme I don't have to create a new email ( myemail+somerandomtext@gmail.com goes to myemail@gmail.com for instance).  Of course if you're worried about stackexchange itself, you'll need an anonymous email, but as long as the question is well written and uses the correct tags, it'll get attention and you can still leave comments on it and the answers. No account, no link to your other questions or "real" self.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more on the plus addressing scheme? I've had to create a new email. Are you saying that such action was not necessary?

Comment: @JordanJamingsons http://lifehacker.com/144397/instant-disposable-gmail-addresses or search google for "gmail plus addresses" and you should find many other references.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will consider that in the future (as you say, it should save some time if not worried about SE folks). Thank you.